# Maven Error when running Makefile in parallel

Tags: maven, makefile

I am running tests in parallel using Makefile and Maven. My Makefile looks like this:

```
...
Mac-Chrome:
    mvn clean test -Dcucumber.filter.tags=@Smoke -DBrowser=chrome -DplatformName="OS X" -DdeviceName="Computer" -DplatformVersion="Ventura" -DScreenDisplay="Wide" -DRunOnBrowserStack=true -DImportResultToXray=true
Mac-Safari:
    mvn clean test -Dcucumber.filter.tags=@Smoke -DBrowser=safari -DplatformName="OS X" -DdeviceName="Computer" -DplatformVersion="Ventura" -DScreenDisplay="Wide" -DRunOnBrowserStack=true -DImportResultToXray=true
    
parallelTesting:
    make -j SamsungS22-Chrome SamsungTabS8-Chrome SamsungTabS8-Firefox SamsungS22-Chrome SamsungS22-Firefox Win10-Chrome Win10-Edge Win10-Firefox Mac-Chrome Mac-Safari
```

But when I run the file, some builds go through but most run into this Maven error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) on project guestcheckout: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete C:\Users\...
```

Is there any way to avoid these problems with cleaning the target files?

Comment: That's an issue on windows because if one process is accessing file/directory it's locked exclusively... the other process can not delete the directory or the file... and no that's a problem Windows...Question: Why do you need to run a make file? For What purpose? You might create a parameterrized tests and run that from Java only ??

Comment: There are some threads that do not do well when running them in parallel from Java only.  And since I have a lot of devices, I will get enough parallels like that.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found was to just drop the clean.

But mysteriously then only 2 or 3 or the jobs are actually build.

When I run it several times, the jobs actually executed are also different.